# Loop continuing after return statement, how to stop it

Tags: python, function, loops, return, continue

Function `next_c` continues to run after `return True` is reached, and then returns `none` later.

I've placed print statements all over to find out what is running. "Check 1" in the if statement right before the return statement prints, then the else statement runs immediately after. 
If I put `return True` immediately before the problem if statement I get the expected results for the rest of the program.

```
import numpy as np

A=[ ["I","L","A","W"],
  ["B","N","G","E"],
  ["I","U","A","O"],
  ["A","S","R","L"] ]



def next_c(atemp, x, y, word): #make a subarray from atemp and check to next c
    suba = atemp[x-1:x+2:,y-1:y+2:]
    for n in range(3):
        for m in range(3):
            if word[0] == suba[n][m]:
#here is the problem
                if len(word) == 1:
                    print("Check1")
                    return True
                else:
                    #change temp array char to 0 then get new sub array coords
                    atemp[x][y] = 0
                    x = x + n -1 
                    y = y + m -1
                    next_c(atemp, x, y, word[1:])


def look(atemp, word, size):#look for 1st c in temp array
    for x in range(size+1):
        for y in range(size+1):
            if atemp[x][y]==word[0]:
                atemp[x][y] = 0  #replace letter with a 0 
#this should return True but always gets None
                if next_c(atemp, x, y, word[1:]):
                    print("Check2")
                    return True

def find_word(board, word):
    a = np.array(board)
    a = np.pad(a, 1, "constant")
    if look(a, word, len(board)):
        return True
    return False

print(find_word(A, "BINGO")) #this should be True
```

After `print('Check1')` I expect the return statment `True` to go to `if next_c(atemp, x, y, word[1:]):` so that `print('Check2')` is executed followed by the final return of `True` from `find_word`.

Comment: Double check tabs vs spaces

Comment: Maybe return the result of the recursion: `return next_c(atemp, x, y, word[1:])`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp yes - the one in the next_c function at the end of the else. I think Johnny's found your problem

Comment: right if you comment out `next_c(atemp, x, y, word[1:])` you will not get "check1" printed

Answer (score 0):

You neglected to trace your recursion.  Try this for starters:

```
            if len(word) == 1:
                print("Check1")
                return True
            else:
                #change temp array char to 0 then get new sub array coords
                atemp[x][y] = 0
                x = x + n -1 
                y = y + m -1
                print("Check 2: before recur")
                next_c(atemp, x, y, word[1:])
                print("Check 3: after  recur")
```

Output:

```
Check 2: before recur
Check 2: before recur
Check 2: before recur
Check1
Check 3: after  recur
Check 3: after  recur
Check 3: after  recur
Check 2: before recur
Check 3: after  recur
False
```

The problem is that you fail to return any Boolean value other than the base case `True`.  You hit your "Check1" point and return `True`, but then the next call up the stack ignores the return value.  This means that for any but a degenerate case, `next_c` returns `None` (the default return value), and that's what gets passed back to `look`, then `find_word`.  `None` is a "falsey" value, so `find_word` converts that to an explicit `False`, which is what the main program receives.

Put the required `return` in place on that recursive call.  Then we get:

```
Check 2: before recur
Check 2: before recur
Check 2: before recur
Check1
Check2
True
```

Note how the program no longer falls off the end of the innermost `else` block -- "Check 3" never appears, since the code returns just before.

Comment: Thanks. I get the answer and applied it. I still don't know why when it returns "True" it doesn't exit the function immediately...oh, I get it. I thought that every loop continued to the end before starting the next. Now I really do get it... I hope.